# Exported object returns undefined

Tags: javascript, parceljs

I have the following singleton inside my `app.js` code:

```
const TodoManager = (function () {
    const allTodos = [];

    return {
        addNewTodo: function (title, color) {
            allTodos.push(new Todo(title, color));
        },
    };
})();
```

and I would like to export the `addNewTodo` function to another `.js` file, so I attached this to end of `app.js`:

`module.exports = TodoManager`

then, on my `dom.js` file (the file I want to use the `addNewTodo` function), I imported it:

`import TodoManager from './app.js';`

However, everytime I try to access any of its objects, it returns `undefined`. Am I doing something stupidly wrong?

(I am using Parcel.js as a bundler)

Comment: *everytime I try to access any of its objects* Can you show how you're trying to access them?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes! so, on my `dom.js` file, if I attach `console.log(TodoManager.addNewTodo())`, for instance, it states that `.addNewTodo()` is not a function

Comment: You might have a circular dependency, resulting in `TodoManager` not being defined at the time you expect

Comment: @CertainPerformance mmm interesting, so perhaps I should be using async, right? could you show me how is it done?

Comment: No, using an async function wouldn't solve the problem. Hard to say without seeing the full code, to see where the circular dependency is

Comment: @CertainPerformance okay! i will look into it. if it doesn't bother you, my code is here: https://github.com/kibebr/afazeres/tree/master/src either way, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
// app.js
require("./dom.js");

const TodoManager = (function () {
  // ...
```

You also have

```
// dom.js
import TodoManager from './app.js';

const MenuBar = (function(){
  // ...
```

This is a circular dependency. When one of the files runs, it sees that it needs to import the other, so control flow switches to the other. Then, the other sees that it needs to import the first file. But the first file is already being in the process of getting created, so it doesn't switch back. The interpreter understands you have a potential issue, but it doesn't throw an error, it tries to run the script the best it can, by setting the export of the original file to an empty object initially. But this results in bugs.

But, in your code, `app.js` does not actually do anything with the `require("./dom.js");` - there's no need for `app.js` to depend on `dom.js`. So, all you really need to do is remove `require("./dom.js");` from `app.js`.

Comment: you're the man! thank you so much, now I'll go on to learn more about circular dependency. just a quick question, since I removed `require("./dom.js")`, I had to add a new `<script>` referring to `dom.js` in my `index.html`. do you know if bundlers such as Parcel.js and Webpack will accept that? so far all the examples I have seen with bundlers is that there is only one `.js` file entrypoint

Comment: Usually, if you have a circular dependency, the right thing to do is to figure out how to structure the code to remove it. Sometimes there are hacks that can let you leave it in (regardless of the bundler you use), but they're quite a code smell.